# Library to render graphics as ASCII-art on a terminal?

Tags: graphics, terminal, render, ascii-art

The title speaks for itself. We use OpenGL to render realistic images, but what if we weren't able to connect to a graphical user interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [LibAA](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) it should do what you want. Hopefully ;)

Answer (score 1):

Written in JavaScript (Node.js) with both CLI and API: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/image-to-ascii